# How to take an average of dataframe by pieces?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one column. I want to take an average of first two numbers than the next two numbers and so on.

```
Example_data_frame
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8

Resulting_data_frame
   1.5
   3.5
   5.5
   7.5
```

I would like to take an average. So that the result is similar to what you see in the Resulting_data_frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible vectorized approach

```
colMeans(matrix(df1$v1, nrow = 2))
## [1] 1.5 3.5 5.5 7.5
```

---

Some benchmarks against `tapply` (that was deleted by now...)

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = sample(1e6))

system.time(with(df1, tapply(v1, as.numeric(gl(nrow(df1), 2, nrow(df1))), FUN = mean)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 11.28    0.03   11.73

system.time(colMeans(matrix(df1$v1, nrow = 2)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.01    0.00    0.01
```